# Best Recursive Subdivision Tiling Mapping Function

Tags: geometry, recursion, conformal-geometry, tiling, transfinite-recursion

I am trying to create subdivision tilings inspired by the work of Brian Rushton ([eg. page 77 of this paper](https://scholarsarchive.byu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2839&context=etd)). The challenge is to subdivide tiles according to a certain rule, and then apply this rule recursively to the result.

For example, a square might be subdivided by [this rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4ORA.png) which splits it into 5 more quadrilaterals. Each of these must then be subdivided again by the same rule, but since the tiles to subdivide are no longer square, a mapping function must be applied to find the vertex positions of the child tiles. What is the best mapping function to use? [Here is an illustration of what I mean.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YggpI.png)

I think the definition of best is:

- Vertices on the edges of the un-mapped tile end up on the edge of the mapped tile.
- All vertices stay within the parent tile.
- The appearance of the child tiles are distorted as little as possible.

I am developing a web app that makes this process interactive which is [here](https://oscarsaharoy.github.io/subtiles), and you can try out the two functions that I have explored so far, but they both have issues. If you would like to experiment or contribute the source code is on github [here](https://github.com/OscarSaharoy/subtiles)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at Cannon, Floyd & Parry's subdivide and tilepack programs ?
https://personal.math.vt.edu/floyd/research/software/subdiv.html
Designed to create input files for Ken Stephenson's CirclePack software
http://www.circlepack.com/software.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I think their software is the best way to do it :) I am wondering how to use it in my app, maybe I will need to read through the source code for that. I think it is also worth noting that due to the circle-packing approach, only convex tiles can be created with this method

Comment: I think you can define any shape you want as the Riemann Mapping Theorem applies